# Windows test network folder permissions for another account

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, network-share, windows-command-prompt

How to test that an account other than login account has access to a network folder ?

Here's an example :

I'm logged in as `steves` but I need to test if `joej` has access to :

```
\\contoso\dept\finance\payroll\taxes\
```

Comment: Check Joe's Effective Access on the folder.

Comment: Maybe something like this to check NTFS ACL permission via PowerShell which I think you are asking since you added that as a tag `(Get-Acl -Path "\\contoso\dept\finance\payroll\taxes\").Access | Select FileSystemRights, AccessControlType, IdentityReference | FL`. If you can check via the GUI way, do that but if you need to check programatically quicker or larger scale, start with something like that. You may need to cross check via AD cmdlet if `joej` is a member of any listed `IdentityReference` AD groups though, but that's just trivial to figure out but see if this is a better starting point